# Git remove file without other on the team having it deleted

Tags: git

If I use the command like following:

```
git rm --cached file.txt
```

I have the `file.txt` deleted from the local repository, but it still exists on the drive physically.

However, whenever other people pull this change - their file gets deleted from their folder. And then I have to send them the file over Skype or something like that.

Question: Is there a way to stop tracking changes in the file, but not have it to be deleted when others pull the changes?

Comment: Do you want the others on your team to still have the old file when they pull or do you want them to have a new version?

Comment: Example: I no longer want the git to track .htaccess file, because there are changes in it for dev site and for test site and for real-life-server. If I remove .htaccess from git tracking, all other people on the team get their .htaccess deleted - which ruins their local website copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply tell Git to stop tracking the file:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file.txt
```

then you can delete it locally, changes won't affect other members.

If you want to start tracking this file again, use `--no-assume-unchanged` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? For me, that's too close to what gitignore does. Do you mean "make Git stop tracking the file"?

Comment: Will this work for other team members who are working on this project?

Comment: @Toly yes, when you stop tracking a file, it won't be affected when you push your changes.

Comment: What if someone else working on the project edits their file and pushes the changes?